# What single method is used to check: blank? && !false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a method (preferably just one Rails or Ruby method) that will validate if a variable is blank but is not `false` (since I have some boolean variables that should not be blank? == true since they have values).

Say I have four types: `nil, '', 0, false`.

I am looking for a simple method that is equivalent of the following:

`(var.nil? || var == '') && var !== false`

This is the simplest I can come up with:

`var.blank? && var !== false`

If there's no other way, then I guess I'll just have to create a custom-method for this.

Comment: You wrote so many different conditions so that your question is not clear. What exactly do you want? Do you want `blank?`, or do the four "different types" play any role in defining what you want, or do you actually want to check for the three objects `nil`, empty string, and `false`?

Comment: You're coming from javascript, aren't you?

Comment: I don't get it: `var.blank? || var == false`. `false.blank?` returns true (as you mentioned), so it fits the general case. You should be able to just use `var.blank?`. Of course, it all breaks with `0.blank?`

Comment: Like Sergio is saying: `var.blank?` will evaluate exactly the same as `var.blank? or var == false`. Please clarify why you can't use `var.blank?`.

Comment: It looks like my OP paragraph got deleted. I stated it there that false.blank? is true. But I wanted it to be false. Since I have some boolean variables that are only either true or false, however they shouldn't be blank since they have values. Therefore, the simplest I can think of is `var.blank? || var == false` so that it can handle those boolean variables as well. Var is an arbitrary variable, it can be String, FixNum, NilClass, or Boolean.

Comment: It's still not clear why you can't use `var.blank?`. `var.blank? || var == false` gives EXACTLY THE SAME RESULT as `var.blank?`, whatever the value of `var` is. Is the problem that your definition of "blank" is not the same as Ruby's? In that case the solution is switching to a programming language that has the same definition of "blank" as you have.

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry, I got confused. It should have been `var.blank? && var !== false`. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that your question became understandable, I shall answer.

```
(var.nil? || var == '') && var !== false
```

can be simplified to:

```
var.to_s.empty?
```

You cannot do it in a single method, but you can do it in two. <strike>It will also return `true` for `[]`, `{}`, for example.</strike>

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I really need. Thank you.

Comment: `[].to_s` and `{}.to_s` both used to return `""` until Ruby 1.8.7. In newer Ruby versions, it returns `"[]"` and `"{}"` respectively and thus is not `empty?`.

Answer (score 6):

> I am looking for a simple method that is equivalent of the following:

```
var.nil? or var == '' or var == false
```

The method you're looking for is `blank?`

```
def foo1(var)
  var.nil? || var == '' || var == false
end

def foo2(var)
  var.blank?
end

foo1(nil) == foo2(nil) # => true
foo1('') == foo2('') # => true
foo1(false) == foo2(false) # => true
foo1(0) == foo2(0) # => true
```

### After edit

> I am looking for a simple method that is equivalent of the following:

```
(var.nil? || var == '') && var !== false
```

Yeah, just make a custom method. Or, if you're feeling particularly evil, you can patch `FalseClass#blank?` to return the opposite value.

Comment: The OP wrote that false is not blank (in the OP's sense). I wonder how this fits here. The OP's description is contradictory anyway.

Comment: @sawa: yeah, it kinda is. I skipped all verbal fluff and relied on the code ("I want the equivalent of")

Comment: Hi. Apologies. I got confused. I edited my question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ohh I see... Thanks! I was just wondering if there's a Rails or Ruby way I'm missing of since this really means a lot to me (I'll need to change a lot of code if not using just one single method that I can find-and-replace-all) Thanks again :)